# pthreads and C++

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am playing with C++ and pthreads and so far so good. I can access a class member function if it's static and I've read that I can access a normal class member functions if I pass "this" as an argument with pthread_create, because c++ does this to, under the hood. But my problem is that I want to give an int to that function, and I don't know how to do multiple arguments with pthread_create.

Answer (score 6):

Pass a struct pointer.

```
struct Arg {
  MyClass* _this;
  int      another_arg;
};

...

Arg* arg = new Arg;
arg->_this = this;
arg->another_arg = 12;
pthread_create(..., arg);
...
delete arg;
```

Comment: What do I do with the _this in the c++ function? Nothing?

Comment: @user: To "access a normal class member functions".

Comment: I think I was unclear, to let pthread_create execute c++ functions they need to be static. I would like them not to be static, if that is possible.

Comment: @vincentkriek: The functions can be non-static, but you need to make sure `this` is not thread-local (and doesn't live on the stack).

Answer (score 0):

you can try boost thread library and use boost::bind() 
Here's an example,

```
class MyThread
{
public:
    MyThread( /* Your arguments here */) : m_thread(NULL)
    {
        m_thread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyThread::thread_routine, this));
    }

    ~MyThread()
    {
        stop();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        if (m_thread)
        {
            m_thread->interrupt(); 
            m_thread->join();
        }
    }

private:
    void thread_routine() {... /* you can access a/b here */}


private:
    int a;
    int b;
    boost::thread *m_thread;
};
```