# Function for the thread within a class in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm having troubles with creation of the function, that should handle new thread. When I create it outside of the class, everything works allright, but when I want to create it inside a class, I can't realize, how to call it.

I call the function with:

```
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL,
        sendMessage, (void *) fd);
```

and the function itself looks like this:

```
void * sendMessage(void *threadid) {
    string message;
    const char * c;
    char buffer[200];
    int fd = (long) threadid;
    while (true) {
        cin >> message;

        if (message == "exit") {
            break;
        }

        c = message.c_str();
        strncpy(buffer, c, sizeof ( buffer));
        send(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    }
}
```

but when I declare it within a class e.g. `void * Client::sendMessage(void *threadid)` , I can't even build it because I get `main.cpp:90:37: error: argument of type ‘void* (Client::)(void*)’ does not match ‘void* (*)(void*)’` Does anybody have any idea, what can cause it and how to fix it?

Comment: Is it just me or are you not using any data members? Why put it in a class in the first place then? If you need to, make it static.

Comment: is there any particular reason not to use std::thread?

Comment: Make the function static or use c++0X threading facilities

Comment: why it has to be static? I don't see any good reason for that :-/ ... nevertheless you were right... making it static solves the problem...

Comment: Because in normal functions there is a implicit this pointer(of the instance) but not in callback like function as your thread function.

Comment: @Dworza because non-`static` member functions must be called against a particular instance of the class (and accept a "hidden" `this` argument, changing the function signature). Combine that with the simple fact that the `pthread_create` function knows nothing about instances, classes, member functions or even C++ and the reasons should be quite clear.

Comment: @not-sehe: I'm C++ newbie so maybe it should be better, but I've decided to use pthread, because I'm programming it on Windows and I need that programme to be able to run on linux as well...therefore I use posix lib...

Comment: @hetepeperfan + NikBougalis thx for the explanation

Comment: @Dworza, Standard libraries are cross-platform.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pthreads and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468113/pthreads-and-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a quick demonstration of how `std::thread` can quickly make all your woes disappear (by seemlessly integrating with `std::bind` style invocation):

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

void some_function(int i, std::string bla) 
{ 
}

struct some_class
{
    void some_member_function(double x) const
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(&some_function, 42, "the answer");
    std::thread t2;

    {
        some_class instance;
        t2 = std::thread(&some_class::some_member_function, 
                std::ref(instance), 
                3.14159);

        t2.join(); // need to join before `instance` goes out of scope
    }

    {
        auto managed = std::make_shared<some_class>();
        t2 = std::thread([managed]() 
                { 
                    managed->some_member_function(3.14159); 
                });

        // `managed` lives on 
    }

    if (t1.joinable()) t1.join();
    if (t2.joinable()) t2.join();
}
```

Comment: If I'd use thread instead of pthread, will I be able to run some function from some class in it's own thread? It seems to me from your example, that it's possible, but I'm not sure

Comment: Yes. See `t2`. I've shown two approaches, one that requires you to manage the lifetime of the `some_class` instance, and one that does it "magically" for you. For your interest: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=25f0f3906d84a8ef97945d247e5a9842-c7de6e91a3d2775d02cca8b7bcb1b42c